# Error while using dlmModReg

Tags: kalman-filter

I have started coding a Kalman filter in R. I am using dlmModreg to build an object of class dlm, which I am planning to use as my input to dlmFilter. But, I am stuck in the dlmModreg step itself. I am providing the parameters for dlmModreg as described in [1](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/dlm.pdf).  This is my code

```
linear.reg     <- lm(y.learn$hospitalizations ~ y.learn$google);
flu.model      <- dlmModReg(y$google,dV=25.66,dW=0.001016);
```

I get the following error

```
Error in dlmModReg(y.learn$google, dV = 25.66, dW = 0.001016) : 
Inconsistent dimensions of arguments
```

For dV I used the residual variance obtained from the linear model(linear.reg)
However, this error vanishes when I remove dW.

Also if I change my code as

```
dlmModReg(y.learn$google, dV = 25.66, m0 = 0.023711, c0 = 0.001016)
```

I get the error below

```
Error in dlmModReg(y.learn$google, dV = 25.66, m0 = 0.023711, c0 = 0.001016) : 
unused argument(s) (c0 = 0.001016)
```

Here m0 is the Beta(google) estimate and c0 is the Beta(google) variance.

I am not sure what is the right value to be used for parameters dW, dV, m0, c0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dlmModReg` has two states in it, an intercept and a slope, so `dW` needs to be two elements long. A quick way to check what you need is to do `dlmModReg (y$google)` and see what prints out. (Or perhaps `str (dlmModReg (y$google))` for a more compact view.)

That would show you that `W` is a 2x2 matrix, while `V` is 1x1, and hence you can specify it as a single number.

As for your other error, remember that R is case-sensitive and the parameter is `C0` not `c0`.

DLMs are wonderful, and the `dlm` package is the easiest to use, but you really do have to poke around under the hood to understand what it's doing for you.

Comment: Thank You for responding. But, I still have some trouble understanding what each parameter is. What is dW, the variance of Beta(intercept) and Beta(google)? Is M0 the estimated value of beta(intercept) and Beta(google)? Kindly confirm. What is the difference between C0 and dW in this case? Thank You.

Comment: Have you checked the vignette for the dlm package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf